# how to plot a figure with specific distance between each line

Tags: r

Actually I try to plot a figure but it puts and shows all the columns(lines) on each other so it is not representative. I try to make a simulated data and show you how I plot it, and also show you what I want

I don't know how to make a data like example i show below but here what I do

```
set.seed(1)
M <- matrix(rnorm(20),20,5)
x <- as.matrix(sort(runif(20, 5.0, 7.5)))
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,M))
```

After making the data frame, I will plot all columns versus the first one by melting it and using ggplot

```
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape)
dff <- melt(df ,  id.vars = 'V1')
b <- ggplot(dff, aes(V1,value)) + geom_line(aes(colour = variable))
```

I want to have specific distance between each line (in this case we have 6) something like below. in one dimension it is V1, in another dimension it is the number of column. I don't care about the function , I just want the photo

Comment: Please provide your data in a reproducible format

Comment: For four columns this is pretty straightforward, but I presume that you want to apply this to a larger number of columns?

Comment: @Mol I have no idea why my code didn't work on your data set.. Sorry!

Comment: are you certain that we need a 3000x34 data set to help you?

Comment: @rawr yes because the example data is not representative

Comment: not sure to understand: do you want a ggplot2 solution? would you like a 3D plot? or is it the part you don't care about and do you 'just' want to reproduce the pasted image?

Comment: @Vincent Bonhomme I don't care which function you use, 3D, ggplot or whatever else, I want to have a simple way to reproduce that figure

Comment: before I write an answer, can you confirm me that you would be happy with such [a plot](http://imgur.com/PikABMQ)? it requires some customization, but if you're happy with it, I turn my code into a nice function. Also, how are defined the colours?

Comment: @Vincent Bonhomme  it is cool. if you can also remove the box in front and make it like above photo ? the colours as you wish

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This solution uses [`rgl`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgl) and produces this plot:

[image]

It uses this function that accepts 3 arguments:

- `df`   : a `data.frame` just like your 'M' above
- `x`    : a `numeric vector (or a 1-col`data.frame`) for the x-axis
- `cols` : (optionnal) a vector of colours to repeat. If missing, black line are drawn

Here is the function:

```
nik_plot <- function(df, x, cols){
  require(rgl)
  # if a data.frame is
  if (is.data.frame(x) && ncol(x)==1)
    x <- as.numeric(x[, 1])
  # prepare a vector of colors
  if (missing(cols))
    cols <- rep_len("#000000", nrow(df))
  else
    cols <- rep_len(cols, nrow(df))
  # initialize an empty 3D plot
  plot3d(NA, xlim=range(x), ylim=c(1, ncol(df)-1), zlim=range(df), xlab="Mass/Charge (M/Z)", ylab="Time", zlab="Ion Spectra", box=FALSE)
  # draw lines, silently
  silence_please <- sapply(1:ncol(df), function(i) lines3d(x=x, y=i, z=df[, i], col=cols[i])) 
}
```

Note that you can remove `require(rgl)` from the function and `library(rgl)` somewhere in your script, eg at the beginning.

If you don't have `rgl` installed, then `install.packages("rgl")`.

Black lines, the default, may produce some *moiré* effect, but a repeating color palette is worse. This may be brain-dependant. A single colour would also avoid introducing an artificial dimension (and a strong one).

An example below:

```
# black lines
nik_plot(M, x)
# as in the image above
nik_plot(M, x, "grey40")
# an unreadable rainbow
nik_plot(M, x, rainbow(12))
```

The 3D window can be navigated with the mouse.

Do you need something else?

---

**EDIT**

You can build your second plot with the function below. The range of your data is so large, and I think the whole idea behind shifting upwards every line, prevent having an y-axis with a reliable scale. Here I have normalized all signals (0 <= signal <= 1). Also the parameter `gap` can be use to play with this. We could disconnect the two behaviors but I think it's nice. Try different values of `gap` and see examples below.

- `df`   : a `data.frame` just like your 'M' above
- `x`    : a `numeric vector (or a 1-col`data.frame`) for the x-axis
- `cols` : (optionnal) a vector of colours to repeat. If missing, black line are drawn
- `gap`  : gap factor between individual lines
- `more_gap_each`: every n lines, a bigger gap is produced...
- `more_gap_relative`: ... and will be `gap` x `more_gap_relative` wide

Here is the function:

```
nik_plot2D <- function(df, x, cols, gap=10, more_gap_each=1, more_gap_relative=0){
  if (is.data.frame(x) && ncol(x)==1)
    x <- as.numeric(x[, 1])

  # we normalize ( 0 <= signal <= 1)
  df <- df-min(df)
  df <- (df/max(df))
  # we prepare a vector of colors
  if (missing(cols))
    cols <- rep_len("#00000055", nrow(df))
  else
    cols <- rep_len(cols, nrow(df))
  # we prepare gap handling. there is probably more elegant
  gaps <- 1
  for (i in 2:ncol(df))
    gaps[i] <- gaps[i - 1] + 1/gap + ifelse((i %% more_gap_each) == 0, (1/gap)*more_gap_relative, 0)
  # we initialize the plot
  plot(NA, xlim=range(x), ylim=c(min(df), 1+max(gaps)), xlab="Time", ylab="", axes=FALSE, mar=rep(0, 4))
  axis(1)
  # finally, the lines
  silent <- lapply(1:ncol(df), function(i) lines(x, df[, i] + gaps[i], col=cols[i]))
}
```

We can use it with (default):

```
nik_plot2D(M, x) # gap=10
```

And you obtain this plot:

[image]

or:

```
nik_plot2D(M, x, 50)
```

[image]

or, with colors:

```
nik_plot2D(M, x, gap=20, cols=1:3)
nik_plot2D(M, x, gap=20, cols=rep(1:3, each=5))
```

or, still with colours and but with larger gaps:

```
nik_plot2D(M, x, gap=20, cols=terrain.colors(10), more_gap_each = 1, more_gap_relative = 0) # no gap by default
nik_plot2D(M, x, gap=20, cols=terrain.colors(10), more_gap_each = 10, more_gap_relative = 4) # large gaps every 10 lines
nik_plot2D(M, x, gap=20, cols=terrain.colors(10), more_gap_each = 5, more_gap_relative = 2) # small gaps every 5 lines
```

[image]

Comment: is it also possible to make a 2D plot like above ? (each column with a specific distance above the other one)

Comment: do you mean something like this: `plot(x[, 1], M[, 5], type="l", xlab="x title", ylab="y title")` ?

Comment: yes but it is only for one column (profile) look at above figure I pasted in my question

Comment: that's a brand new plot (and a much better one I feel). Also updated my answer.

Comment: it seems very cool and I do appreciate your answer already. I would like to know if it is possible to color set of them separately like each five or each three columns a specific color , if it is possible ?

Comment: you have done a lot and I already liked your answer which I am going to accept too. However, I need one more favour, is it possible to make it in a way that if I need to have 5 or 2 or whatever columns in a bigger distance than the rest or each 3 or 5 of them close to each other but distance from others ?

Comment: I have modified the answer and the function and the examples.

Comment: that is very good but then I have no option if i want to split them for example if I do nik_plot2D(M, x) it makes them each 10 close together so I do have the first 2D you made

Comment: Changed defautl parameters for arguments. See the first example with `#no gap`, it should do the job.

Comment: just removed them!

Answer (score 5):

As other have pointed out, your data have very large peaks and it's not clear whether you want to allow some curves to overlap,

[image]

```
m <- read.table("~/Downloads/M.txt", head=T)

fudge <- 0.05
shifty <- function(m, fudge=1){
  shifts <- fudge * max(abs(apply(m, 2, diff))) * seq(0, ncol(m)-1)
  m + matrix(shifts, nrow=nrow(m), ncol=ncol(m), byrow=TRUE)
}
par(mfrow=c(1,2), mar=c(0,0,1,0))
cols <- colorRampPalette(blues9[4:9])(ncol(m))
matplot(shifty(m), t="l", lty=1, bty="n", yaxt="n", xaxt="n", ylab="", col=cols)
title("no overlap")
matplot(shifty(m, 0.05), t="l", lty=1, bty="n", yaxt="n", xaxt="n", ylab="", col=cols)
title("some overlap")
```

Alternatively, some outlier/peak detection scheme could be used to filter them out before calculating the shift between curves,

```
library(outliers)

shifty2 <- function(m, outliers = 10){
  tmp <- m
  for(ii in seq_len(outliers)) tmp <- rm.outlier(tmp, median = TRUE)
  shifts <- max(abs(apply(tmp, 2, diff))) * seq(0, ncol(m)-1)
  m + matrix(shifts, nrow=nrow(m), ncol=ncol(m), byrow=TRUE)
}

matplot(shifty2(m), t="l", lty=1, bty="n", yaxt="n", xaxt="n", ylab="", col=cols)
```

[image]

(there are probably good algorithms to decide which points to remove, but I don't know them)

Answer (score 0):

For 3D plotting I prefer the rgl package.  This should be close to your desired solution.
The color of each scan changes on every third one.

```
library(rgl)
M<-read.table("M.txt", sep="\t", header = TRUE, colClasses = "numeric")
x<-read.table("x.txt", sep="\t", header = TRUE)
n<-ncol(M)
M[M<1]<-1
plot3d(x='', xlim=range(x$Time), ylim=c(1, n), zlim=(range(M)), box=FALSE)
sapply(seq(1,n), function(t){lines3d(x$Time, y=t*10, z=(M[,t])/10000, col=t/3+1)})
title3d(xlab="scan", ylab="time", zlab="intensity")
title3d(main ="Extracted Spectra Subset")
axes3d()
#axis3d(edge="x")
#axis3d(edge="y")
#axis3d(edge="z")
```

Do the huge differences in magnitude of the data points, I needed to scale some factors to make a readable graph.  The intensity of the goes from 0 to nearly 1,000,000, thus distorting the graph.  Attempted to normalize by taking the ln, but plot became unreadable.