# how to combine all my columns in one sorted column

Tags: r

I have a data like this

```
    V1       V2       V3    V4
1   0.700   1.400   0.850   1.600
2   2.083   1.650   1.633   1.900
3   2.517   2.100   2.117   2.117
4   2.667   2.267   2.267   2.300
5   3.883   3.017   3.567   9.717
6   NA     3.383    5.350   21.600
7   NA        NA    9.700   NA
8   NA        NA    15.867  NA
```

if you need to use it in R, simply use a reproducible example as below

```
df<- structure(list(V1 = c(0.7, 2.083, 2.517, 2.667, 3.883, NA, NA, 
NA), V2 = c(1.4, 1.65, 2.1, 2.267, 3.017, 3.383, NA, NA), V3 = c(0.85, 
1.633, 2.117, 2.267, 3.567, 5.35, 9.7, 15.867), V4 = c(1.6, 1.9, 
2.117, 2.3, 9.717, 21.6, NA, NA)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", 
"V4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

I want to combine all of them in one column and sort them

my expected output is like below

```
0.7
0.85
1.4
1.6
1.633
1.65
1.9
2.083
2.117
2.1
2.267
2.3
2.517
2.667
3.017
3.383
3.567
3.883
5.35
9.7
9.717
15.867
21.6
```

melting the data is one way like

melt(data) , but is there another way to sort and get them all in one array?

Comment: `sort(unlist(df, use.names = FALSE))` ?

Comment: @David Arenburg thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `unlist` and then `sort`

```
dfN <- data.frame(Col1= sort(unname(unlist(df))))
```

Comment: You don't need `na.omit`. `sort` has `na.last = NA` as default.

Comment: @akrun great thanks ! I liked it and I will accept it in 6 minutes

Comment: @akrun I don't know why your solution does not work on my real data https://gist.github.com/anonymous/76fc277b354684035d801f0a86b338ce, it does not sort it

Comment: @Mol Can you check the `str(df)` in your original data ie. check whether the columns are `factor` class or `character` etc...

Comment: @Mol I tried `link <- "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/76fc277b354684035d801f0a86b338ce/raw/d1a97e63c8a66342a8bef081a6294f01d0abe8ae/data.txt"; 
df <- read.csv(link, sep=""); head(data.frame(Col1= sort(unname(unlist(df))))[,1])#
[1] 0.117 0.117 0.150 0.183 0.200 0.200; tail(data.frame(Col1= sort(unname(unlist(df))))[,1])
#[1] 99.700 99.700 99.717 99.850 99.850 99.917`  It is `sort`ing for me.

Comment: @akrun I did str(df) and it is for the first one  'data.frame': 111 obs. of  68 variables:
 $ V1  : Factor w/ 80 levels "","0.7","16.217",..: 2 8 9 10 26 36 52 3 4 5 ...

Comment: @Mol I think you `read` the data incorrectly.  If you look at my earlier comment, it is reading correctly. i.e.  `str(df)#
'data.frame':   111 obs. of  68 variables:
 $ V1  : num  0.7 2.08 2.52 2.67 3.88 ...
 $ V3  : num  1.4 1.65 2.1 2.27 3.02 ...
 $ V5  : num  0.85 1.63 2.12 2.27 3.57 ...
 $ V7  : num  1.6 1.9 2.12 2.3 9.72 ...
----`

Comment: @akrun Actually I don't read it from any where but manipulating it from another data. this is my first data https://gist.github.com/anonymous/24d4182897130ed9a88421acfb08ac29   then I select only odd column using  odd <- seq(1, ncol(Mydf), by = 2) and then I make a data frame based on that mdf <- Mydf[,odd] and then I use your command

Comment: @Mol  I read from the github data you showed.  It is working for me.   Even for manipulating the data, you have to read it from somewhere.  The code for subsetting is not the problem.  The initial reading is the problem.

Comment: @akrun  you are definitely right , I added the sep=" " in the original and I found it works. Can you please have a look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36448950/how-to-sort-all-alternative-columns-and-assign-value-to-it